# Using new keywords in Racket macros

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

As an exercise in Racket, I am trying to create a C-like function, accepting the `return` keyword.

When I define the `function` macro:

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))
(define-syntax (function stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    #:datum-literals (return)
    [(_ (func-id arg-id ...)  body ...)
     #'(define (func-id arg-id ...)
         (call/cc (lambda (return) body ...)))]))
```

and create a *function* `f` with a `return` statement:

```
(function (f x) (return 100) (+ 1 x))
(f 2)
```

I get:

```
return: undefined;
cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

However, expanding the `function` macro:

```
(require macro-debugger/expand)
(syntax->datum (expand-only
                #'(function (f x) (return 100) (+ 1 x))
                (list #'function)))
```

returns:

```
'(define (f x) (call/cc (lambda (return) (return 100) (+ 1 x))))
```

and in fact:

```
(define (f x) (call/cc (lambda (return) (return 100) (+ 1 x))))
(f 2)
> 100
```

works as expected.

For my dummy case, it is possible to replace the pattern matching in `function`  definition like so:

```
[(_ (func-id arg-id ...) (return x-expr) body ...)
 #'(define (func-id arg-id ...)
     (call/cc (lambda (return) (return x-expr) body ...)))]
```

But in general the `return` keyword can occur anywhere in the function body.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

I think you misunderstand what `datum-literals` means. `datum-literals` is for pattern matching input syntax, not for output template/syntax.

What you attempt to do couldn't be done purely by rewriting rules because Racket's hygienic macro system will rename your `return` into something else to avoid name collision.

The usual way to do this is using syntax parameter. [*Fear of Macros*](https://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/Syntax_parameters.html) explains this really well already, so I won't repeat it here.

Comment: I am still unable to apply `make-rename-transformer`, anyway I obtained a working code. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I expected I needed an argument  `(make-rename-transformer #'(return_k val))`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))
(require racket/stxparam)
(define-syntax-parameter return
  (lambda (stx)
    (raise-syntax-error (syntax-e stx) "can only be used inside aif")))

(define-syntax (function stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ (func-id arg-id ...) body ...)
     #'(define (func-id arg-id ...)
         (call/cc (lambda (return_k)                      
                    (syntax-parameterize ([return (syntax-rules () [(_ val) (return_k val)])])
                      body ...))))]))
(function (f x) (return 100) (+ 1 x))
(f 2)
```

I suppose  `syntax-parameterize`  can be improved with `make-rename-transformer`, but I did not  succeed in that.